# initWithStyle not being called in UITableview from storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am working on a project where I am trying to use this framework [VPPDropdown](https://github.com/vicpenap/VPPDropDown)
But I want it to work with `storyboard`.

So what did I do? I dragged a `UITableviewController` on screen. Then in my code I have this.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _dropDownSelection = [[VPPDropDown alloc] initSelectionWithTitle:@"Selection Combo"
                                                               tableView:self.tableView
                                                               indexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:kRowDropDownSelection inSection:kSection1]
                                                                delegate:self
                                                           selectedIndex:1
                                                           elementTitles:@"Option 1", @"Option 2", @"Option 3", nil];

        _dropDownDisclosure = [[VPPDropDown alloc] initDisclosureWithTitle:@"Disclosure Combo"
                                                                 tableView:self.tableView
                                                                 indexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:kRowDropDownDisclosure inSection:kSection1]
                                                                  delegate:self
                                                             elementTitles:@"Disclosure 1", @"Disclosure 2", @"Disclosure 3", @"Disclosure 4", @"Disclosure 5", nil];


        NSMutableArray *elts = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            // just some mock elements
            VPPDropDownElement *e = [[VPPDropDownElement alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Element %d",i] andObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
            [elts addObject:e];
        }

        _dropDownCustom = [[VPPDropDown alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Combo"
                                                        type:VPPDropDownTypeCustom
                                                   tableView:self.tableView
                                                   indexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:kRowDropDownCustom inSection:kSection2]
                                                    elements:elts
                                                    delegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

After some research I found out that when you use a `UITableViewController` inside a `storyboard`. The method above is not being called. And that you should put that code inside:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ( !(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) ) return nil;

    // Your code goes here!

    return self;
}
```

When I do that I get the following error

> `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/stefgeelen/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/6D0EF4BF-068C-493C-A1A5-CFAA2B935D56/claesdistribution.app> (loaded)' with name 'DR7-d0-mee-view-dDq-is-22f''`

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: And everything works if you don't implement `initWithCoder`.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Interface Builder, you should put initialization code in this method instead:

```
- (void)awakFromNib
{

}
```

Note: There is no [super awakFromNib] to call though and don't call [super initWithStyle] either.

It should also be noted that many UI elements in the controller may not yet be initialized in awakFromNib so some of that should be better accessed in viewDidLoad.